# Как отделить python код от команды def

Tags: python

```
def hi():
...  print("hi")
...  print("bye")
```

Как сделать так, что-бы `print("bye")` не участвовал в коде?

Comment: Ну так и не надо внутри функции писать

Comment: Shush1k как это сделать???

Comment: Я написал ниже, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отступы очень важны в данном языке, поэтому то, что внутри функции будет и выполнятся в ней

```
def hi():
...  print("hi")
print("bye")
```

**PS:**

```
def hi():
    print("hi")

print("bye")
```

Comment: Я знаю, но как сделать так, чтобы что-то было в функции, а что-то нет. Не делать отступ, на этом сайте не работает

Comment: На сайте все работает вам просто нужно прочитать, как размещать код. В данном примере, в функции `hi()` выводится сообщение "hi", а вывод сообщения `print("bye")` никак не связано с функцией `hi()`

Comment: @Mikayel возможно вы пытались сделать отступы при помощи табуляции, здесь это не работает, нужно ставить пробелы

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Mikayel чтобы поблагодарить, можете отметить зеленой галочкой мой ответ, она находится рядом с моим ответом.